# Webpack Error - You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type,

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I was trying to add webpack config in my react project, but i am facing issue as when i run the project , i get an error which says -

```
ERROR in ./src/index.js 14:2
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (14:2)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
| 
| ReactDOM.render(
>   <React.StrictMode>
|     <App/>
|   </React.StrictMode>,
```

here below is my configuration for webpack.config.js

```
const path = require("path");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
module.exports = {
  entry: path.join(__dirname, "src", "index.js"),
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.?js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
          options: {
            presets: ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"],
          },
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: "./public/index.html",
      filename: "./index.html",
    }),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin(),
  ],
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".js", ".jsx"],
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/i,
        use: [
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, // instead of style-loader
          "css-loader",
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jp(e*)g|svg|gif)$/,
        use: ["file-loader"],
      },
      {
        test: /\.svg$/,
        use: ["file-loader"],
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Your configuration has 2 `module` keys. They conflict with each other. Merging them should resolve your issue:

```
const path = require("path");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
module.exports = {
  entry: path.join(__dirname, "src", "index.js"),
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: "./public/index.html",
      filename: "./index.html",
    }),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin(),
  ],
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".js", ".jsx"],
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.?js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
          options: {
            presets: ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"],
          },
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/i,
        use: [
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, // instead of style-loader
          "css-loader",
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jp(e*)g|svg|gif)$/,
        use: ["file-loader"],
      },
      {
        test: /\.svg$/,
        use: ["file-loader"],
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

Comment: umm that did solved my issue but now i am getting the same error in  <div className="header row flex-middle"> appropriate loader needed :(

Comment: I guess the html-loader will do it: https://webpack.js.org/loaders/